# JavaScript / CoffeeScript rename id of cloned nested div assigned to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I would like to clone the `outer_div` in the html below using CoffeeScript in my Rails app and then change the `id` of `inner_div` to an `mSec` timestamp.

### View

```
<div class="col-xs-12" id="outer_div">
  <div class="col-xs-3" id="inner_div">
    Hello World
  </div>
</div>

<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit_button" class="btn add-text-input">

<div class="col-xs-12" id="new"></div>
```

### CoffeeScript

```
ready = ->
  $("#submit_button").click ->
    date = new Date
    mSec = date.getTime()
    name = $('#outer_div').clone()
    name.attr 'id', mSec          # <-- need to change this line of code
    $("#new").append(name);
  return
$(document).ready(ready)
```

The `name.attr 'id', mSec`code changes the `id` of the `outer_div`, but I would like to change the `id` of the `inner_div`. What changes do I have to make to my code to target the `inner_div'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) on `name` to search for `#inner_div` within your clone:

```
name.find('#inner_div').attr(id: mSec)
```

That will give you the `id` attribute you're after but you'll still have duplicate `id="outer_div"` elements and that's not valid HTML. You should change the `id` attribute on `name` too; you probably don't need the `id` on the clone so you could use [`removeAttr`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) to remove it:

```
  name.removeAttr('id').find('#inner_div').attr(id: mSec)
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/rd25b2ey/